# Select dropdown value in jquery based on value from db

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I have a HTML dropdown list with single selection. I want to select a value according to an value which I get from the database.

```
<select name="aa">
    <option>BE</option>
    <option>TE</option>
    <option>SE</option>
</select>
```

I get the value "TE" from the db and then I tried these 3 ways of setting the associated option tag selected.

```
if($m_aa == "TE"){
$script = <<< EOF
<script type='text/javascript'>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        // $('#aa option:contains("' + BE + '")').attr('selected', 'selected'); //won't work
        // $('#aa option:eq(0)').attr('selected', 'selected'); //won't work
        $('#aa option:eq(1)').prop('selected', true); //won't work
     });
</script>
EOF;
echo $script;
}
....

<dropdown list>
```

But none of the 3 possibilities will work.
Firebug don't show any error, if I add an alert(); it will shown. So syntactically it should be fine. I use jquery version 1.8.6 within a wordpress plugin in which this functionality I mentioned above should be implemented.

BR,
mybecks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To set the selected option of a `<select>` you can use the `.val()` function:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $('#aa').val('<?php echo $m_aa; ?>');
     });
</script>
```

Also, I noticed that you have `<select name="aa">`, you should add `id="aa"` as well for the code to work, or change the selector to `$('select[name=aa]')`.

Comment: Actually his only error was trying to select the option by id when it should be by name. So only changing the selector to this `$('select[name="aa"] option:eq(1)').prop('selected', true);` works very well. Your alternative should work well also.

Comment: Thanks for your answers & comments. @Christoffer solution works great for me, using it with dynamic data. :-)

Answer (score 0):

try using jquery version 1.7.x